# The number $38$ is the least positive integer with the property that its square ends with three fours $(38^2=1444)$.

Tags: number-theory

The number $38$ is the least positive integer with the property that its square ends with three fours $(38^2=1444)$ . What is the next least positive integer with such property?

I began with writing down $1000x+444=y^2$. This tells that the number is a perfect square divisibly by 4. Also, since the last digit is 4, the only possible last digit of the number is either 2 or 8 only. Hence, I reduced the possibilities to

$?12,?28,?32,?48,...,?92$ where ? is the third digit. I can't find a way to find for the third digit. Or is there any easier way of doing this?

Comment: Just because $y^2$ is divisible by $4$ does not mean that $y$ itself is divisible by $4$. Indeed, note that 38 is not divisible by $4$

Answer (score 2):

$x^2\equiv444\mod1000\implies x^2\equiv4\mod 8$ and $x^2\equiv69 \mod 125$

$\implies x\equiv \pm2\mod 8$ and $x\equiv \pm 38\mod 125$.

Solving these shows the next solution is $x\equiv 462\mod 1000$.

Comment: $538$ and $962$ are also solutions

Comment: essentially used the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: in divisibility language, $1000$ divides $x^2-38^2$ means $125$ and $8$ divide $x\pm38$

Comment: Can you please tell me how you got $x\equiv 462$?

Comment: If $x=8m-2=125n-38$ then $8m+36=125n$ so $36\equiv 125n\mod8$ so $4\equiv5 n \mod8$ so $n\equiv4\mod8$ so $x=125n-38\equiv500-38=462\mod1000$

Comment: @ERROL  Actually we don't need to solve any CRT system since we can get the other two roots from $\ \large (x+2n)^2\equiv x^2\pmod{\! 4n}\ $ - see my answer.

Comment: @J.W.T. It seems you may have overlooked $\,x^2\equiv 38^2\iff x\equiv \pm 38\ $ is true $\bmod 125\ $ & $\bmod 8\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque:  isn't that what I indicated in my comment that starts "in divisibility language"?

Comment: I refer to your answer where you appear to be solving a CRT system (else why did you write $\,x^2\equiv 69\mod 125$ ... solving these ...?)

Comment: I wrote $x^2\equiv69\mod125$ because OP asked for $x^2\equiv444\mod1000,$ and $444\equiv69\mod125,$ but in the next line of my answer I wrote $x\equiv\pm38\mod125$ because I knew from OP that $38^2\equiv444(\equiv69)\mod125$; I do like your $(x+2n)^2\equiv x^2\mod 4n$ though

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-Just to exhibit another way.

The digit $a_0$ should be $2$ or $8$.

►$x=10^3M+10^2a_2+10a_1+2\Rightarrow x^2=10^3X+100a_1^2+400a_2+40a_1+4=10^3Y+444$ where $M,X$ and $Y$ are integers.This implies $$100a_1^2+40a_1+400a_2=1000Y+440\iff a_1^2+4a_2=10Y+\frac{110-10a_1}{25}$$ Hence $a_1=1$ or $a_1=6$ (in order the fraction be an integer).The value $a_1=1$ is discarded because it gives $4a_2=10Y+3$. But $a_1=6$ gives $34+4a_2=10Y$ whose solutions are  $a_2=4$ and $a_2=9$.

Thus the only solutions ending in $2$ and having at least three digits are all the integers ending in $462$ and $962$.

Similarly  with

►$x=10^3M+10^2a_2+10a_1+8$
We get $5a_1^2+8a_1-69=0$ so $a_1=3\text { and }-\dfrac{23}{5}$ then $a_1=3$ is the only solution for $a_1$. The other digit $a_2$ can be calculated as follows
$$x^2=10^4a_2^2+76\cdot10^2a_2+1444=10^3Y+444$$ so we get $$10a_2^2+\frac{76}{10}a_2+1\in\mathbb N$$ and the only solution is now $a_2=5$.

In short there are only four natural integers whose squares end in $444$ (**being the fourth digit other than $4$**) which are $38,538,462$ and $962$.

Comment: Simpler: notice the roots are preserved under $\,x \to x+500\,$ - see my answer.

Comment: I will do it. I usually don't see the other answers in the first instance. When I don't solve on time, I try to find a different answer after reading the answers already given. Regards

Answer (score 1):

There exist $4$ roots by CRT lifting $\,x^2\equiv 38^2\,$ mod $\,8\,$ & $\,125.\,$ We know two: $\, 38\,$ & $\,-38\equiv 962.\,$ The other two are $\,38\!+\!\color{#c00}{500}\equiv 538\,$ and $\,-538 \equiv 462\,$ by $\,(x\!+\!\color{#c00}{500})^2\equiv x^2\pmod{\!1000}.\,$ So $462$ is next.